# Getting another table's record based on matching IDs

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

**Table 1: dit_news**

```
1. id
2. title
3. body
4. date
5. posterID
```

**Table 2: dit_users**

```
1. id
2. fullName
3+ a bunch of irrelevant to this problem columns
```

`dit_news.posterID` equals that of `dit_users.id`

I need a way of getting the `fullName` record where the dit_users's ID equals that of `posterID`in `dit_news`. I hope that makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT dit_users.fullName FROM ditusers INNER JOIN dit_news ON dit_users.id = dit_news.posterID
```

Comment: Awesome - would you mind accepting the answer if it solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct u.fullName
from dit_users u
inner join dit_news n on n.posterID = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    dit_users.fullName
FROM
    dit_news
    JOIN dit_users ON
        dit_news.posterID = dit_users.id
;
```

You may want to add `WHERE dit_news.id = N` to retrieve the name of the user for article N only.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.fullname
FROM dit_users u
   JOIN dit_news n ON (n.posterid = u.id)
WHERE n.id = 12345
```